# Pattern matching/excluding (awk/sed)

Tags: awk, sed

I use the following to retrieve all interfaces from a configfile - but to exclude interfaces having "no ip address" or "shutdown".

`awk "/^interface/,/\!/" file | sed -E '/^interface/{:1;N;/\!/!b1;/(no ip address|shutdown)/d}'`

How can I also exclude interface Vlan12 (in this case) since I cannot match on 'ip address' (or 'shutdown')?

```
lldp run
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
!
interface Vlan12
 ip flow ingress
 no ip redirects
!
interface Vlan18
 no ip address
 ip flow ingress
!
interface Vlan23
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
 no ip redirects
!
interface Vlan100
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 shutdown
!
ip classless
```

Expected result:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
!
interface Vlan23
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
 no ip redirects
!
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for something like `awk 'NR==1{RS=ORS="!";next} /\n ip address/ && !/shutdown/' file`?

Comment: What are the rules to exclude an interface here? Is it because `interface Vlan12` is named `Vlan12`?

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail -it works like a charm. I'm always learning something new...

Comment: @Ryszard Czech: No, the "rules" were more in the line of "since the word 'ip address' is missing - exclude the interface block".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
sed ':a;/^interface /{N;/\n!$/!ba};/\n *ip address/!d;/shutdown/d' yourfile
```

The script, written on more line is:

```
:a                 # lable a to come back to
/^interface /{     # body of {} only executed on lines starting with "interface"
  N                # add next line to pattern space
  /\n!$/!ba        # if last added line is not just a !, jump to :a
}                  # all preceding lines up to this act like a do-while loop
/\n *ip address/!d # delete multiline if there's no line in it starting with "ip address"
/shutdown/d        # delete multiline if "shutdown" occurs in it
```

You can clearly make each regex simpler or more complex, depening on your needs.